# SQL Azure Schema issue error code 208 with temporary table

Tags: azure, stored-procedures, schema, temp-tables

I have a couple of stored procedures that create different temporary tables.
At the end of the procedure i drop them (know that is not required, but it's good practice).

The stored procedures are executed as a part of a SSIS package. I got 4 different SQL jobs that execute the same SSIS package running in parallel.

When logging into the Azure portal and using the performance recommendation feature, I get a recommendation to fix the schema issues. It states an Sql error code 208. According to documentation that means "object not found".

Temporary tables are valid within the scope of the stored procedure and should get a unique name in the database, so I do not think where are any conflicts.

I have no idea what causes this, and the stored procedures seems to work alright. Anyone know what could be the cause here?

Simplified sample of one of the procedures:

```
        SET NOCOUNT ON;

    CREATE TABLE #tmpTransEan
        (
          Ean_Art_Str_id BIGINT ,
          Artikler_id BIGINT
        );

    INSERT  INTO #tmpTransEan
            ( Ean_Art_Str_id ,
              Artikler_id
            )
            SELECT  DISTINCT
                    eas.Ean_Art_Str_id ,
                    a.Artikler_id
            FROM    dbo.Artikkel_Priser ap
                    JOIN Ean_Art_Str eas ON eas.artikler_id = ap.Artikler_id
                    JOIN wsKasse_Til_Kasselogg ktk ON eas.Ean_Art_Str_id = ktk.ID_Primary
                    JOIN dbo.Artikler a ON a.Artikler_id = eas.artikler_id
                    JOIN dbo.Felles_Butikker b ON b.Butikker_id = ap.butikker_id
            WHERE   ktk.ID_Table = OBJECT_ID('Ean_Art_Str')
                    AND LEN(a.Artikkelnr) >= 8
                    AND ktk.Tidspunkt >= @tidspunkt
                    AND ( ( ap.butikker_id = @nButikker_id1
                            AND @Alle_artikler_til_kasse = 'N'
                          )
                          OR ( b.Databaser_id = @Databaser_id
                               AND @Alle_artikler_til_kasse = 'J'
                             )
                        )
                    AND b.Akt_kode = 'A'
                    AND a.Akt_kode = 'A'
                    AND a.Databaser_id IN ( -1, @Databaser_id )

    SELECT  DISTINCT
            a.Artikkelnr ,
            s.Storrelse ,
            eas.* ,
            EAN_12 = LEFT(eas.EAN_13, 12)
    FROM    dbo.Ean_Art_Str eas
            JOIN #tmpTransEan t ON t.Artikler_id = eas.artikler_id
            JOIN Artikler a ON a.Artikler_id = eas.artikler_id
            JOIN dbo.Felles_Storrelser s ON s.Storrelser_id = eas.storrelser_id


    DROP TABLE #tmpTransEan;
END;
```

Comment: Can you post your SP logic?

Comment: Hard to say without any code. But you can `drop table if exists ...`, and I think you can now `select * from tempdb..sysobjects...` to try to avoid issues with temporary tables. *Local* temporary tables have *session* scope. Are your "SQL jobs" executing in parallel in a single session? Are you certain your error message is related to using temp tables?

Comment: Added a simplified code sample of one of the procedures. The temp table is a local one defined with a single #, so checking if it exists should not be necessary i think.

I am not entirely sure how the SQL job agent kicks off the jobs, but the job is defined as 4 separate jobs starting at different time intervals but running at the same time.

Comment: To be clear, this is a SQL Server instance running in Azure (not Azure SQL), and you're using SQL Server Agent jobs. The four different Agent jobs happen to be running at the same time--running *concurrently* rather than running *in parallel*. Is that right?

Comment: Yes that is correct. It is a SQL Server running on the Azure platform. The SQL Job agent is running on an on premise SQL server.

Comment: The jobs are setup using the SQL Manager's job agent. Each job runs in an infinite loop spinning through a result set executing the stored procedures with different input parameters.